# TeamViewer: I'm worried the user who used my PC stole some data

Tags: windows

How can I be sure that the user yesterday connected to my PC with TeamViewer downloaded some data with the file transfer?

Does the file transfer shows a notification to say that he is downloading something? Is there a log to be sure of what he did?

In the connections.txt file I see this line only:

```
#####9641       19-10-2014 15:48:19 19-10-2014 15:54:14 Office  RemoteControl   {4E1642D0-E1EE-4C9D-96FB-0E99E88B5FD5}
```

Can I know if he downloaded something using the file transfer feature without letting me know of that?

Comment: File transfers are initiated, I do not know of a way to download files that were not initiated by the remote user on TV.

Comment: you can test it by connecting top your machine from another machine to try to perform a file transfer

Comment: @John can you provide a bit more information.  Were you aware they were connecting at the time, and just want to know if they could have downloaded something without your knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

There is a log for file transfers in TeamViewer, however, if the user had unattended access to your PC (s)he could delete this log file - or the user could have uploaded said file to a filesharing service (such as DropBox) which would not show up in the log.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look in the TeamViewer Log file (on Windows you find it here: `%APPDATA%/TeamViewer`, mine is called `TeamViewer9_Logfile.log`.

Look for lines like this:

```
2014/10/21 16:25:07.450  3664  3636 G2   CClipboardSource::SendClipboardContent: (8 data formats)
```

For best results search for `Clipboard` in you text-editor.

It indicates that the user copied something over the clipboard (wich works surprisingly well with TeamViewer). It would be enough to click on the file, press `CTRL`+`C` and paste it on his own Desktop.

Using this method won't create the file-dialog window, so you won't notice it until you take a look on the log.

Comment: In C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\TeamViewer\MRU\RemoteSupport There is no file...